# Does the inclusion map $\iota: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ induce an inclusion of co/homology groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold, and $\iota: \mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the natural inclusion homomorphism of abelian groups. Then, it is easy to check that we obtain a well defined induced map $\iota_*:H_i(M,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_i(M,\mathbb{R})$ for each $0\leq i\leq n$. Need this map be injective? I suspect that it might not be given that $H_i(M,\mathbb{Z})$ could have a torsion subgroup which would necessarily have to be mapped identically to zero given that $H_i(M,\mathbb{R})$ must be be torsion free.

If we instead consider cohomology, then I am unsure of how to obtain an induced $H^i(M,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^i(M,\mathbb{R})$ since it seems that the natural map on the cochain complexes should go $S^i(M,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow S^i(M,\mathbb{Z})$ and be given by the pullback of $\iota$. But then the induced cohomology map goes $H^i(M,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H^i(M,\mathbb{Z})$ so I must be doing some thing wrong here.

Any help on ironing out these ideas without appealing to the universal coefficient theorem would be lovely.

Comment: Your comments in the first paragraph are correct: there is a map and it need not be injective for the reason you say. To define cohomology, you take homomorphisms from the chains to the coefficient group, and you can compose $C_n(M) \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ to get an induced map from $C^n(M; \mathbb{Z}) \to C^n(M; \mathbb{R})$, and hence on cohomology.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I don't see how the second map works. Isnt $C^n(M,\mathbb{Z})=\text{Hom}(C_n(M,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Exactly, so a map $C_n(M) \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a cochain with integer coefficients. Now compose with the ring map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ to get a cochain with real coefficients.

Comment: But $C_n(M)$ is the chains with integers coefficients, so how do we turn a map $C_n(M)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ into a map $C_n(M,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first paragraph is correct: integral homology may have torsion, and therefore the map $H_n(M; \mathbb{Z}) \to H_n(M; \mathbb{R})$ cannot always be an inclusion.

The definition of the $n$th cochain group with coefficients in an abelian group $A$ is
$$
C^n(M; A) = \textrm{Hom}(C_n(M; \mathbb{Z}), A).
$$
(Note the coefficients in the chain group.) Therefore given a group homomorphism $\phi: A \to B$, there is a map
$$
C^n(M; A) \to C^n(M; B)
$$
defined by $f \mapsto \phi \circ f$. This will commute with the differential and so it will induce a map on cohomology. In particular, there is a map
$$
H^n(M; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^n(M; \mathbb{R}),
$$
which cannot always be an inclusion for the same reason as for homology.

Comment: Oh so we don't look at the chain group with coefficients in $A$ for cohomology?

Comment: The standard definition is to use the chain group with integer coefficients. Have you seen it done differently?

Comment: I believe you if that’s standard, I think I was just having trouble parsing notation